# Launching the application is slow using FlaUI , application and program not syncing

Tags: flaui

public void Execute()
{

```
    using (var automation = new UIA3Automation())
    {
        
        using (var app = FlaUI.Core.Application.Launch(PRCDFileLocation))
        {
            log.InfoFormat("Launch {0}", PRCDFileLocation);

          
            Window window = app.GetMainWindow(automation, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5000));
         //FlaUI.Core.Input.Wait.UntilResponsive(window.FindFirstChild(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5000));


        if (window != null)
            log.InfoFormat("Main Window {0} is found", PRCDFileLocation);

            log.WarnFormat("Configuration Menu {0} is not found", PRCDFileLocation);

            
            if (EnablePIOScript)
                StartupLoadPio(window);

            if (EnableEventScript)
                StartLoadEvent(window);
        }
    }
```

}

if i run the program , the application launches but the program is not moving forward , i added thread.sleep not working , once the launch method is initiated , the application takes time to open so i added timespan.fromseconds . but after the application is launched StartupLoadPio should be executed but the application is not running automatically as expected . there is log attached to the program